# Why is Angular loading my root template twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

My root component is loading twice even though I have a separate component for my homepage. I have tried to use different things, such as `pathMatch`, separate component, etc, but no luck. When I go to `/dashboard`, it works just fine, but when it loads the page initially (root page), the navbar is loaded twice. I want to avoid that.+

My code looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RootComponent } from './root/root.component';
import { FeatureDashboardComponent } from '@angular/dashboard';
import { FeatureHomepageComponent } from '@angular/homepage';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RootComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      { 
        path: '',
        component: FeatureHomepageComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: FeatureDashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
    RootComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [RootComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And my HTML for RootComponent is:

```
<angular-navbar></angular-navbar>
<div class="layout">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And navbar is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand">My App</a>
    </div> 
</nav>
```

[Example in inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMsd2.png)

Comment: Can you create your example in https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with this code:

```
path: '',
component: RootComponent,
```

you most likely do NOT want to have your RootComponent here as it would allow the RootComponent to appear within your

```
<router-outlet>
```

and could explain why you have 2 of them.

```
<router-outlet>
```

should only route to CHILDREN of your RootComponent.

In other words, no route (in your routing config) should render your RootComponent it's already being rendered.  The routes there should only render what you want to display WITHIN your router-outlet, aka CHILDREN of your RootComponent

For the solution I think you just have to make this:

```
path: '',
component: FeatureHomepageComponent
```

the first path in your config (delete the RootComponet part and the children:[] part)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you have the route `''` loading the `RootComponent` and the children route tries to load `FeatureHomepageComponent` but is also `''`, which can't be effectively resolved by the router.

Try giving the children route a path that is not empty, like this:

```js
...
{
    path: '',
    component: RootComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'home',
        component: FeatureHomepageComponent
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

And play with the redirect at the end, so when your application loads, it should navigate to (for example) `localhost:4200/home`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the `router-outlet` try to call to the exact component name

Comment: I want my RootComponent to be the root of all other components. So that the navbar can ALWAYS show on top of each component. I think if I use exact component name, I won't be able to achieve that.

Comment: @user746019 were you able to fix this? I am stuck on the same issue. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This means you have either of two: another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` instance or you are instantiating the `<angular-navbar></angular-navbar>` in another template other than the one you show here.  `pathMatch` has nothing to do here because the `<angular-navbar></angular-navbar>` component is route agnostic, meaning it is a layout component.